# Select an attribute from object in a List inside another List

Tags: c#, select

Can I perform a select using ternary operator to get an attribute from object inside a list?

Here is my model:

```
public class Xpto
{
    public List<Son> Sons { get; set; }
}

public class Son
{
    public string Names { get; set; }
}
```

And here i would like to get "Name" attribute for each son that i have:

```
var result = (from a in mylist
          select new
          {
              sonsNames = a.Sons == null : <What should i put here?>
          }).ToList<object>();
```

I've tried `Sons.ToString()` but it prints an object reference.

I would like to have a string list in "sonsNames" and each name separeted by a ','. Example: sonsName: 'george, john'.

Comment: [And here i would like to get "Name" attribute for each son that i have]; okay, so does that mean you want all of them strung together for each row in `myList`? Furthermore, what is `myList`? Do you want a different row for each `Son`?

Comment: We can't say what to "put there" unless you tell us what should be there for those objects where `a.Sons` is null.

Comment: I would like to separate each Name using a ',' ... example: sonsNames: 'george,john'

Comment: I would recommend using string.Join(): string names = string.Join(",", Xpto.Sons.Select(s => s.Names).ToArray());

Comment: You know, I would love to answer this question. I really would. But I'm confident it's better to teach you to fish. First you need to know how to string together a set of strings (https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=separate%20each%20Name%20using%20a%20comma%20c%23) and then how to get to that set of strings in a `select` (https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=linq%20select%20string%20property) ... PSST, the 4th one down on the second query is really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about this ?

```
//set up a collection

   var xptos = new List<Xpto>() 
            { new Xpto() 
            { Sons = new List<Son> 
                { new Son() { Names = "test1" },
                  new Son() { Names = "test2" } 
                }
            },
          new Xpto() 
          {
             Sons = new List<Son> {
             new Son() { Names = "test3" } 
           }
           }};    

 //select the names
var names = xptos.SelectMany(r => r.Sons).Where(k => k.Names != null)
           .Select(r => r.Names + ",") .ToList();

names.ForEach(n => Console.WriteLine(n));
```

[Here's more info on SelectMany()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534336%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)